# Can PostgreSQL with synchronous streaming replication get behind on the WAL logs?

Tags: replication, postgresql-9.4, standby, write-ahead-logging

I have 2 Postgres 9.4 servers running on 2 identical VMs that I am using to learn how to setup replication before it gets used in production.  Hot standby isn't required but it would be preferred.  I setup the replication following [this guide](http://www.unixmen.com/setup-postgresql-replication-centos/), though I'm on Ubuntu  14.04 using the Postgres repository, and quickly verified it works by running pgbench and looking at both servers.

Under the documentation for 9.4 for streaming replication, I need to set `wal_keep_segments` to a high enough value in case the standby server gets behind, but does that only apply to asynchronous streaming replication, or does it also apply to synchronous? Forgive me if I missed that in the docs.  Otherwise I'll have to setup replication slots to make sure the wal doesn't get behind.